# How do I use Thymeleaf th:each to print a list objects in divs, not <td>

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I have a list of objects that I pass to a frontend JSP page. I need to display each value in its own div.

For example:

```
<div class="objects">
    <div class="object"></div>
    <div class="object"></div>
    <div class="object"></div>
    <div class="object"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

Is there any way to do it this way as opposed to putting it in a table and doing `<td>`?

Comment: Change the tags from `td` to a `div`

Comment: Is this work for you: `<div th:each="u : ${users}" th:text="${u.name}">user name</div>`? More on [Thymeleaf Iteration](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#iteration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of Posts data can be printed as below in div

```
<div th:each="tempPost:${posts}">
     <div th:text="${tempPost.getContent()}"></div>
     <div th:text="${tempPost.getAuthor()}"></div>
     <div th:text="${tempPost.getCreatedAt()}"></div>
</div>
```